# Best python or C/C++ library for delay differential equations

Tags: python, numerical-analysis

Within a python project I am currently working with multi-dimensional delay differential equations with constant time delays. For this purpose, I am looking for an efficient and preferably up to date library for DDE-solvers. I came across the following options:

- PyDelay (outdated?)
- PyDDE (outdated?)
- ddeint (seems to use linear interpolation only)
- diffeqpy which uses DifferentialEquations.jl
- JiTCDDE

I am happy about any suggestions or alternatives. It would be great if the library supports a recent python version (but not a must) and it supports solvers for a wide range of different problems (with constant time delays). Furthermore, I would also be happy with C/C++ packages which I could include as extensions.

Thanks in advance for your suggestions!